# Websocket server: TypeError ws.send() not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, serial-port

I'm starting to use node js. So far everything was good. Untill today.
I was playing with websockets, i'm able to establish a connection between the server and the browser. However, I cannot send messages from the server to the client using ws.send('something');
In almost every example I can find the methode is used, and in my situation it doest not seem to work.
Can somebody explain me why?

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const WebSocket = require('ws').Server;
const router = express.Router();
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const barCode = new SerialPort('COM50', {
    baudRate: 57600
  });

// --------- SETUP WS ---------
var wsport = 8085;
var ws = new WebSocket({port: wsport});

ws.on('connection', function open() {
  console.log('ws connection has been established.');
  // ws.send('something'); this line is not working!

});

// !!-- BarCode:: Log errors to console when they occur.
barCode.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message); 
});

  barCode.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Barcode received:', data);
    ws.send('received barcode');
  });

// --------- SETUP EXPRESS ---------
var app = express();    // Define the application object
var port = 4000;        // Specify the port to listen to

router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

router.get('/offline',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/offline.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || port);
console.log('Webserver running at port ' + port);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `In almost every example I can find the methode is used,` not from the docs it's not.    https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#sending-and-receiving-text-data  IOW: try -> `ws.on('connection', function open(ws) {`   Also might be worth changing the var called ws in your case to wss to match docs's and save confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common mistake
The thing here is the

```
var ws = new WebSocket({port: wsport});

ws.on('connection', function open() {
  console.log('ws connection has been established.');
  // ws.send('something'); this line is not working!
});
```

the variable created as an new Websocket, isn't valid inside the function

```
ws.on()
```

So as **ws** isn't a valid variable inside the function

> ws.send() isn't a function, hence the error

Try calling another function inside **ws.on()**, that has the access to the variable **ws** where the object of the socket was created.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ws_server = new WebSocket({ port: wsport });
ws_server.on('connection', (ws_socket) => {
    ws_socket.send('something'); 
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.